# Qt and regular expressions

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I would like to write simple regexp with Qt QRegExp

I want to fetch all substring of a Qstring with `table(i, d)`, without the quotes, with `i` "hard written" and `d` representing any integer. And then using cap, to retrieve value for `d`. I propose

```
 qREgExp reg ( "table(i,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*)") ;
```

I cherrish the hope that then

```
 reg.cap(2)
```

gives me the `d` in question here.

How would you put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
qREgExp reg ( "\\btable\\(i,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\)" );
```

with

```
reg.cap(1)
```

Comment: Exactly. The parenthesis on the table "call" aren't escaped, and then they are parsed as operators of the regular expression. Escaping them makes them part of the text to match.

Comment: @Spidey thanks!! then `"\\btable\\(i,\\s*(\\.+)\\s*\\)"` should match data(i,1), isnt it ? it is not.

Comment: @Spidey maybe this is better `"\\btable\\(i,\\s*(.+)\\s*\\)"` !? this is matching, but i cannot retrieve the . with cap

Comment: Try "\\btable\\(i,([^\\)]+)\\)".